# Flutter: Update text on screen when MaterialButton is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I'm trying to build a basic dice app with a button. When the button is clicked, the displayed text gets updated with a random number.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

int dice = 0;

void main() {
  int dice = 0;
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Quick Dice'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              rollDice();
            },
            child: new Text('$dice'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void rollDice(){
  dice = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
  print('In Roll Dice()');
  print('$dice');
}
```

When the button is clicked, I can see that the function rollDice() is being called and the value of $dice is being updated but on the screen, the value never gets updated.

Is there something I'm missing? Should the child text element be refreshed somehow to to show the new value on button press?

Comment: You should use setState() in rollDice() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this ( StatefulWidget ) :

```
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: UpdateScreen(),
  ));
}

class UpdateScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  UpdateScreenState createState() => UpdateScreenState();

}

class UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen>{

  int dice = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Quick Dice'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            rollDice();
          },
          child: new Text('$dice'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void rollDice(){
    setState(() {
      dice = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      print('In Roll Dice()');
      print('$dice');
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how the screen is getting updated. But this works. :)

Comment: When you use the StatefulWidget widget and setState the class, widget rebuild, and your changed data will be shown

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

Refer Random [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/Random-class.html)

and use dart.math library [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-math/dart-math-library.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: DiceApp(),
  ));
}

class DiceApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DiceAppState createState() => DiceAppState();
}

var randomNo = new Random();
var dice = randomNo.nextInt(6) + 1;

class DiceAppState extends State<DiceApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dice App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              dice = randomNo.nextInt(6) + 1;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            dice.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 }
```

Your result screen-> [image] | [image]

Answer (score -1):

For updating your data on screen you have to use state management like provider, Getx , block etc. Or you can use the setState method in your rollDice() function then the the widget will rebuild and your data will be updated. Something like this--

```
void rollDice(){
   setState(() {
    dice = Random().nextInt(6) + 1
    });
  print('In Roll Dice()');
  print('$dice');
}
```